# Star trail software

Tags: photography, image-editor

My friend is able to take long exposure photos of stars, but these photos need to be combined into 1 photo to create an image of star trails.

What software can do this?

She does not have Photoshop, so recommendations that also work without Photoshop would be appreciated.

OS: Windows. 
Price: Willing to pay up to $US10 for the software.

Comment: I assume that software should work on Windows? Any price/license concerns (must it be free, or how much would the friend be willing to pay, must the license permit for commercial use)?

Comment: Would panorama software work?  For example Hugin.  I assume the photos are all from the same point and at the same angle, so the software would be stacking the images.  I believe Hugin does that.  http://hugin.sourceforge.net/  and http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Align_a_stack_of_photos.html  Preventing the black sky in one image from obscuring the trails in another might be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of tutorials on the net for how to make star trails using [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) which is a **free**, open source, cross platform and very powerful photo editing tool.

One that I found that was nice and concise was [this](http://rubenlarsson.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/how-to-create-star-trails.html) and the processing steps were:

- Open up GIMP.
- Add all the images into layers. There is no specific order required.
- Change the blending mode of all the layers to Lighten. In GIMP select each layer and change the blending mode in the layers dock (top right).
  You should now have a star trail.

If your camera needed some processing time between each photo, resulting in something resembling LEDs: continue with:

- Flatten your image (Image>Flatten)
- Select a group of star trails that have roughly the same angle (pointing in the same direction). Go to Filters>Blur>Motion Blur… adjust the angle by dragging the angle slider and keep an eye on the effect in the preview window.
- Repeat the above step for all angles of star trails.

[image]

There are even some gimp plugins to automate the process for the user, such as [GIMP Star Trails Compositor](https://github.com/themaninthesuitcase/gimp-startrail-compositor) *or [StarTrails](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25638) for videos*.

[image]

Comment: How many photos would this work for? If you tried to load thousands of layers, I suspect GIMP would run out of memory or crash.

Comment: @vclaw - I think that if you tried it in any way but incrementally for 1000s of high definition photos anything but a super computer would crash. Just take the first 30 combine to one, add 30 & combine etc.